# How to check the value is present inside an array and insert the value into database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need some help. I need to insert the the value if its present inside the user input array using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

> db_images:

```
id         image     subcat_id
```

Here I need to insert into above table as the following json array value.

```
$subcat=array(array("id"=>63),array("id"=>64));
$imageArr=array(array("image"=>"abc.png","id"=>63));
```

Here I need to match both array if any value from `$subcat` array is present inside the second (`i.e-$imageArr`) array then the resepective image will insert into the table and if not present the the blank image value will insert with the respective `subcat_id` . Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every element in the `subcat` array, you can iterate on the `imageArr` and check if the ids match (nested loop), like this:

```
foreach($subcat as $s) {
    $flag = false;

    foreach($imageArr as $i) {
        if ($s['id'] == $i['id']) {
            // insert ($i['image'], $s['id']) into db
            $flag = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    if ($flag == false) {
        // insert $s['id'] into db
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can even do in the following way with the help of `array_column` and `in_array` with loop reduced.

```
<?php

$subcat=array(array("id"=>63),array("id"=>64));
$imageArr=array(array("image"=>"abc.png","id"=>63), array("image"=>"abc.png","id"=>65));

foreach($imageArr as $image){
    /* array_column will do the job with in_array to search in the multi dimension array */
    if(in_array($image['id'], array_column($subcat, 'id'))){
        echo 'exists'. $image['id'].'<br>'; 
    }else{
        echo 'not exists'. $image['id'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Always `$subcat` value is going to insert into database.

Comment: But as per my above example it will work fine. Can you please post your full array so that I will be able to test